# Cognos 10 BI: saving reports

Tags: cognos

Can scheduled reports (defined through query studio) be saved to my documents folder automatically?  There are hundreds of reports defined where I work and I'd like to run and have them saved in my folder without the laborious process of clicking hundreds of times. Unfortunately, I'm constrained to not change or create any reports.

I have at least discovered how to create a job to schedule all the reports at once - and have them save in the cognos server.

Unfortunately email doesn't work as their size is too large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Page 250 of Cognos 10 Installation and Configuration

You can configure Content Manager to store report output to a local drive or
network share by defining an external object store. Report output is available
through IBM Cognos Connection and IBM Cognos SDK, but the report output is
not stored in the content store database. Using an external object store for report output reduces the size of the content store and provides performance improvements for Content Manager.

**Before you begin**

Ensure that you do the following before you create an external object store
connection.

- Provide Content Manager computers with access to the file location of the
  external object store.
- Provide the user account that runs the IBM Cognos service with read and write
  access to the file location.
- Create the content store.

**Procedure**

1. Start IBM Cognos Configuration.
2. In the Explorer window, under Data Access > Content Manager, right-click the
   name of your Content Store, and then click New resource > External Object
   Store.
3. In the New Resource - External Object Store window, type a unique name for
   your file system repository, and click OK.
   You can have only one external object store.
4. Click the name for the repository.
5. In the External Object Store - Resource Properties window, click inside the
   value field, click edit, and when the URI values window opens, type the path
   to your file system location, where file-system-path is the full path to an
   existing file location.

**Windows Destination** `file:///c:/file-system-path` or `file://host/share/file-system-path`

**UNIX or Linux** `file:///file-system-path`

In a distributed installation, all Content Managers must have read and write
access to the file system location. To improve performance when reading
outputs, Application Tier Components, essentially the repository service, should
have read access to the file system location. If they do not have read access,
requests are routed to the active Content Manager.

6. Restart the IBM Cognos service.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to save execution result to a folder. Server folder or any network folder.
This opportunity could be set up by your Cognos server administrator.

Comment: Could you please give me details or a link - I'll have more chance having this set this up if I can provide as much guidance to the admin here.